# what's the meaning of zabbix jmx expression?

Tags: zabbix

{Template JMX Generic:jmx["java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=ParNew",CollectionCount].last(0)}<{Template JMX Generic:jmx["java.lang:type=GarbageCollector,name=ConcurrentMarkSweep",CollectionCount].last(0)}

Comment: The question is not clear. What are you asking? The pasted string is a Zabbix trigger expression which references two JMX item keys with beans.

Comment: yes,it's a Zabbix trigger expression.What does this trigger mean?The number of processes recovered by ParNew less than The number of processes recovered by ConcurrentMarkSweep?I don't know the trigger mean~

Comment: Zabbix expression alerts when `ParNew` garbage collector collection count is less than `ConcurrentMarkSweep` garbage collector collection count.

Comment: "ParNew garbage collector collection count is less than ConcurrentMarkSweep garbage collector collection count" means what?

Comment: That's turning into a Java question now, but basically those are two types of garbage collectors in Java, and this would alert when one of them is more active than the other one. There's overview at https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/our-collectors , and you can find out more at resources like http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html .